# stopping and continuing a SKAction

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, textures, skaction

How we can stop an action on certain frame (texture)? I want to make an animation which stops after the touch is ended. I searched trough the docs, but with no luck. The only thing I have found is  methods removeAllActions and removeActionForKey: but I don't want to completely remove an action, I just want to stop it at the right texture - the current texture when the animating signal is stopped.

```
//This is from the scene init method
NSMutableArray *frames = [NSMutableArray array];


SKTextureAtlas *atlas = [SKTextureAtlas atlasNamed:@"hero-movement"];


int numImages = atlas.textureNames.count;
for (int i=1; i <= numImages; i++) {
    NSString *texture = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"animation_00%d", i];
    SKTexture *t = [atlas textureNamed:texture];
    [frames addObject:t];
}
self.animation = frames;
```

And this is the method which I use in touchesBegan to start animation:

```
-(void)move :(float)delay
{
//This is our general runAction method to make our bear walk.
//By using a withKey if this gets called while already running it will remove the first action before
//starting this again.

[self.hero runAction:[SKAction repeatActionForever:[SKAction animateWithTextures:self.animation
                                                                timePerFrame:delay
                                                                      resize:NO
                                                                     restore:YES]] withKey:@"move"];
return;
}
```

Comment: what are your ways of solving this? Have you tried doing something like touchesDidEnd:withEvent:? What code do you have?

Comment: Here is the code. I tried in touchesEnded to use removeActionForKey: but that removes an action, and sets the texture I don't want.

Comment: well you could use a for loop, and loop through each texture in frames, and when the user lets go of the screen, you could set whatever texture you want to end at, for that specific texture  for (int i = 0; i < frames.count; i++) { frames[i] = frames[whatever_index]; } just a though

Comment: I am not really clear with what you are saying... I need to stop at certain texture, but that need to be a texture based on movement, not chosen by me...

Comment: You can remove the action and you can pause a node which will also pause the node's actions. Those are the things you can do. If you need to keep track about animation frames so you can continue the animation where you left it, you will have to cycle through the frames manually using update: or a sequence with wait and runBlock actions.

Comment: Hi Steffen. What I am trying to do is play an animation based on movement state and the problem is idle state which can be presented with one of four possible textures. Okay, I'll give it a try with manually setting the texture based on states to see what will happen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `speed` property to pause/resume an action:

```
SKAction *action = [_hero actionWithKey:@"move"];

action.speed = 0;    // to pause
```

or

```
action.speed = 1;    // to resume
```

Comment: Thanks, I just tested what you suggested, and it works. I solved a problem already using a sequence with runBlock and wait actions combined, but I can accept this as a working solution also.